# LXAppearance not starting

Tags: crash

On 21.04 lxappearance is not starting. The CL produces:

```
[1]    87961 segmentation fault (core dumped)  lxappearance
```

Is this happening for anyone else? Is there anything I can do at this point, except wait for a fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried submitting a bug report from the crash file?  (`ubuntu-bug /var/crash/[name of file].crash`) as that may provide more details, including if others have reported the issue.  The package you're using is not a Lubuntu package since 18.04, so few Ubuntu *devs* are working on it; it's from upstream debian now only.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Bug report has been submitted. Of hand, do you know of any other apps that allow you to change settings for env's with just a window manager? Right now I'm stuck editing ~/.gtkrc-2.0 and ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini.